# Show $ \frac{x}{xy+x+1}+\frac{y}{yz+y+1}+\frac{z}{zx+z+1}=1 $ given $xyz = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please help me prove the equality: If $xyz=1$, prove that

$$
\frac{x}{xy+x+1}+\frac{y}{yz+y+1}+\frac{z}{zx+z+1}=1
$$

Answer (score 7):

Note that $$\dfrac{x}{xy+x+1} = \dfrac{xz}{xyz+xz + z} = \dfrac{xz}{xz+z+1}$$
Similarly, we get
$$\dfrac{y}{yz+y+1} = \dfrac1{z+1+\dfrac1y} = \dfrac1{z+1+xz}$$
Now add the three terms and finish it off by canceling the numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: Rewrite the $1$ in the first denominator as $xyz,$ so that the left hand side becomes  $$\begin{align}\frac1{y+1+yz}+\frac{y}{yz+y+1}+\frac{z}{xz+z+1} &= \frac{1+y}{yz+y+1}+\frac{z}{xz+z+1}\\ &= 1-\frac{yz}{yz+y+1}+\frac{z}{xz+z+1}.\end{align}$$ Can you go from here?