# Given that $xyz=1$ , find $\frac{1}{1+x+xy}+\frac{1}{1+y+yz}+\frac{1}{1+z+xz}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I think I solved this problem, but I don't feel $100$ percent sure of my solution. We have:

$xy=\large {\frac 1z}$

$xz=\large \frac 1y$

$yz=\large \frac 1x$

So let's substitute these into our sum:

$\large  \frac{1}{1+x+\frac 1z}+\frac{1}{1+y+\frac 1x}+\frac{1}{1+z+\frac 1y}$

If we rewrite with a common denominator we get

$\large \frac{z}{1+z+xz}+\frac {x}{1+x+xy}+\frac{y}{1+y+zy}$

If $\large \frac{1}{1+x+xy}+\frac{1}{1+y+yz}+\frac{1}{1+z+xz}=\frac {x}{1+x+xy} +\frac{y}{1+y+zy}+\frac{z}{1+z+xz}$ , $;$   then $(x, y, z)=1$ and we can compute that the sum is equal to $1$.

The problem I have with this is that I found what $(x, y, z)$  $had$ to be, but I but I only had one weak restriction on the variables. Secondly, what are other way of doing this that I can learn from? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "$(x,y,z)$"? Anyways, another way to try is the "obvious" one: solve $xyz=1$ for one variable, and substitute that into the equation you're trying to sum. It may or may not be more tedious than other methods, but eyeballing it I think it works out nicely.

Comment: I don't understand, $(x, y, z)$ just means "x, y, and z"

Comment: Not an answer, but since we know $xyz = 1$; let $x = y = z = 1$ and we find that the giant expression above equals $1$. If you are asking the *optimal* solution, then that is a different question.

Comment: To answer your other question, the other way to handle this is *Lagrange Multipliers*. I would not recommend it for this problem

Comment: This was asked before: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332188/show-fracxxyx1-fracyyzy1-fraczzxz1-1-given-xyz-1?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We only need to continue a little further on the path you took. The first term is 
$$\frac{1}{1+x+xy}.\tag{1}$$

Consider the **second term**
$$\frac{1}{1+y+yz}.$$
Using your substitution, we (you) find that this is 
$$\frac{x}{1+x+xy}.\tag{2}$$

Consider the third term $\dfrac{1}{1+z+zx}$ and replace $z$ by $\frac{1}{xy}$, and $zx$ by $\frac{1}{y}$. We end up with
$$\frac{xy}{1+x+xy}.\tag{3}$$

Add  up the first term, the second, and the third, or equivalently (1), (2), and (3). We get
$$\frac{1}{1+x+xy}+\frac{x}{1+x+xy}+\frac{xy}{1+x+xy},$$
which is $1$.

Answer (score 11):

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1+x+xy}+\frac{1}{1+z+xz}+\frac{1}{1+y+yz}&=\frac{1}{1+x+xy}+\frac{xy}{xy(1+z+xz)}+\frac{x}{x(1+y+yz)}\\
&=\frac{1}{1+x+xy}+\frac{xy}{xy+1+x}+\frac{x}{x+xy+1}\\
&=1
\end{align*}

Comment: + Nice work, Grumpy!